# Find the direction of the fastest growth of the scalar field

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Find the direction of the fastest growth of the scalar field

$f=xe^{2y}+z^3+xy^2$

at the point p(x,y,z)=(1,0,2)

so i calculated the gradient

$\operatorname{grad} f = < e^{2y} + y^2, 2x e^{2y} + 2xy , 3z^2 >$

so i have now

$<1,2,12>$ is it this direction ? or should i divide it all by lenght of vector?

Comment: The vector that you’ve computed already specifies a direction. Whether or not you need a unit vector depends entirely on the conventions being used in the course you’re taking.